# TransactionAbortedException when masstransit receives message

Tags: exception, msmq, transactionscope, masstransit

For several days I have problem with TransactionScope. Error message is as follows:

```
MassTransit.Context.ServiceBusReceiveContext Consumer Exception Exposed System.Transactions.TransactionAbortedException: The transaction has aborted.
   at System.Transactions.TransactionStatePromotedAborted.CreateAbortingClone(InternalTransaction tx)
   at System.Transactions.DependentTransaction..ctor(IsolationLevel isoLevel, InternalTransaction internalTransaction, Boolean blocking)
   at System.Transactions.Transaction.DependentClone(DependentCloneOption cloneOption)
   at System.Transactions.TransactionScope.SetCurrent(Transaction newCurrent)
   at System.Transactions.TransactionScope.PushScope()
   at System.Transactions.TransactionScope..ctor(TransactionScopeOption scopeOption, TransactionOptions transactionOptions, TransactionScopeAsyncFlowOption asyncFlowOption)
   at MassTransit.Transports.Msmq.TransactionalInboundMsmqTransport.ReceiveMessage(MessageEnumerator enumerator, TimeSpan timeout, Action`1 receiveAction) in d:\BuildAgent-03\work\aa063b4295dfc097\src\Transports\MassTransit.Transports.Msmq\TransactionalInboundMsmqTransport.cs:line 48
   at MassTransit.Transports.Msmq.InboundMsmqTransport.<>c__DisplayClass2.<EnumerateQueue>b__0(MessageQueueConnection connection) in d:\BuildAgent-03\work\aa063b4295dfc097\src\Transports\MassTransit.Transports.Msmq\InboundMsmqTransport.cs:line 96
   at MassTransit.Transports.DefaultConnectionPolicy.Execute(Action callback) in d:\BuildAgent-03\work\aa063b4295dfc097\src\MassTransit\Transports\DefaultConnectionPolicy.cs:line 42
   at MassTransit.Transports.ConnectionPolicyChainImpl.Next(Action callback) in d:\BuildAgent-03\work\aa063b4295dfc097\src\MassTransit\Transports\ConnectionPolicyChainImpl.cs:line 50
   at MassTransit.Transports.ConnectionHandlerImpl`1.Use(Action`1 callback) in d:\BuildAgent-03\work\aa063b4295dfc097\src\MassTransit\Transports\ConnectionHandlerImpl.cs:line 93
   at MassTransit.Transports.Msmq.InboundMsmqTransport.EnumerateQueue(Func`2 receiver, TimeSpan timeout) in d:\BuildAgent-03\work\aa063b4295dfc097\src\Transports\MassTransit.Transports.Msmq\InboundMsmqTransport.cs:line 119
   at MassTransit.Transports.Msmq.InboundMsmqTransport.Receive(Func`2 callback, TimeSpan timeout) in d:\BuildAgent-03\work\aa063b4295dfc097\src\Transports\MassTransit.Transports.Msmq\InboundMsmqTransport.cs:line 45
   at MassTransit.Transports.Transport.Receive(Func`2 callback, TimeSpan timeout) in d:\BuildAgent-03\work\aa063b4295dfc097\src\MassTransit\Transports\Transport.cs:line 59
   at MassTransit.Transports.Endpoint.Receive(Func`2 receiver, TimeSpan timeout) in d:\BuildAgent-03\work\aa063b4295dfc097\src\MassTransit\Transports\Endpoint.cs:line 351
   at MassTransit.Context.ServiceBusReceiveContext.ReceiveFromEndpoint() in d:\BuildAgent-03\work\aa063b4295dfc097\src\MassTransit\Context\ServiceBusReceiveContext.cs:line 91
```

Queues are clear, means transactions are succeeded next time (I think).
There is no related stack trace to this. Maybe ThreadPooling may have something to do with this?

This error began to appear suddenly, there is a couple of days. There were no changes in the code responsible for handling transactions.

I need help. Anyone?

**Update 1:**

This exception is thrown on production server but I can't reproduce it on staging server or dev machine.

**Update 2:**

All transactions are local.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem was in buggy StructureMap. After upgrade everything works fine.

Answer (score 0):

This sounds like an issue with the Microsoft DTC (distributed transaction coordinator), in this case you're likely using a connection to a SQL server while reading the message and that connection is unable to be enlisted into the distributed transaction.

There are many troubleshooting guides related to MS DTC, so you might look into checking for DTC operation, security, and connectivity. It's likely that an account may have expired, a firewall rule changed, or a service not started on one of the nodes.

Comment: Thanks but there is no other nodes and I don't use DTC. Connection to database has Enlist = false statement.

Comment: The problem was in buggy StructureMap. After upgrade everything works fine.